# Docker Nginx PHP Laravel curl failed to connect to api.localhost port 80. Connection refused

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, curl, docker-compose

I am new to docker for Windows and have this setup wherein 2 repos have its own docker-compose.yml file. One is for the API while the other is for the APP.

API `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

networks:
    my_network:
        name: my_network
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.23.0.0/24
services:
    my_api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/site.dockerfile
        container_name: my_api
        ports:
            - 127.0.12.9:80:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        networks:
            my_network:
                aliases:
                    - "api.localhost"
    webserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: webserver_my_api
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - 127.0.12.10:80:80
            - 127.0.12.10:443:443
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - my_network
```

APP `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

networks:
    my_network:
        external: true
services:
    my_app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/site.dockerfile
        container_name: my_app
        ports:
            - 127.0.12.11:80:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        networks:
            my_network:
                aliases:
                    - "app.localhost"
    webserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: webserver_my_app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - 127.0.12.12:80:80
            - 127.0.12.12:443:443
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - my_network
```

Each has its own docker file as well.

Both API and APP have the same `.docker/site.dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# just a bunch of RUN commands to install PHP dependencies

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Nginx conf for API `.docker/nginx/conf.d/app.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass my_api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Then Nginx conf for APP `.docker/nginx/conf.d/app.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass my_app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

After which, I added these lines on my Windows host file.

```
127.0.12.10     api.localhost
127.0.12.12     app.localhost
```

Both `http://api.localhost` and `http://app.localhost` are able to run on my web browser. However, when the APP do a curl request to the API, I get the following error.

`cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.localhost port 80: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://api.localhost`

Both are residing in the same network when I execute `docker network inspect my_network`.

```
"Containers": {
    "0d77c5cc22c36f8086eb8e5d580562354c4c6b3c7bdd962e0f8cebfa7a3d844b": {
        "Name": "my_api",
        "EndpointID": "93bb1cd93ccd09b7c1fd2de3e074525b2fc98919eba0cf2cc96c2112d4e1e1b5",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:09",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.9/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "53432448ea91677c643d2f1ff206dcfdc6209741ba9951da342756f752672ab8": {
        "Name": "webserver_my_app",
        "EndpointID": "09ec9ae65461bcc42a750fb0a4fee8305b299c1ad2f1b8e16c65902119489b0d",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "55c2fef084b249a7b3537c641c7101276d9130c6d81d77b21e88206bd10001ec": {
        "Name": "webserver_my_api",
        "EndpointID": "ad1d3b1bedd140a26aec05de276f6f5edc0631b22fa2e77595f5bdf63d9eabca",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:08",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.8/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "dedfe7f75ef76e913b4483708b9920b7d94f8d4931db74e9831cc86194113d75": {
        "Name": "my_app",
        "EndpointID": "80f2c8e1b83817dda62c682f9ed8e098d8cd3cf4c6d05b3af145e58660368779",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:05",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.5/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
},
```

I am able to do a request via postman as well with no issues. It is just when the APP do a curl on the API.

Anything I missed out?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

[image]

Added screenshot from `docker ps` command

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the answer after hours of trial and error.

Instead of using the alias, in my case `api.localhost`, I used the IPv4 set on the container.

To get the IPv4, I ran `docker network inspect my_network` which gave me this list.

```
"Containers": {
    "0d77c5cc22c36f8086eb8e5d580562354c4c6b3c7bdd962e0f8cebfa7a3d844b": {
        "Name": "my_api",
        "EndpointID": "93bb1cd93ccd09b7c1fd2de3e074525b2fc98919eba0cf2cc96c2112d4e1e1b5",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:09",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.9/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "53432448ea91677c643d2f1ff206dcfdc6209741ba9951da342756f752672ab8": {
        "Name": "webserver_my_app",
        "EndpointID": "09ec9ae65461bcc42a750fb0a4fee8305b299c1ad2f1b8e16c65902119489b0d",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "55c2fef084b249a7b3537c641c7101276d9130c6d81d77b21e88206bd10001ec": {
        "Name": "webserver_my_api",
        "EndpointID": "ad1d3b1bedd140a26aec05de276f6f5edc0631b22fa2e77595f5bdf63d9eabca",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:08",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.8/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "dedfe7f75ef76e913b4483708b9920b7d94f8d4931db74e9831cc86194113d75": {
        "Name": "my_app",
        "EndpointID": "80f2c8e1b83817dda62c682f9ed8e098d8cd3cf4c6d05b3af145e58660368779",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:05",
        "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.5/24",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
},
```

Since `webserver_my_api` is my nginx container, I use its IP address of `172.23.0.8`. Then I ran `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://172.23.0.8');` on my app and it now works!!!

Though this solution works, I still don't see it as the actual solution. The problem with this is that when I restart the containers, these IP addresses will change.

Any long term solution for this? Also, I still want to use `api.localhost` rather than the IP address.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you bind ports with an IP adresse (e.g. : `127.0.12.12:80:80`), you limit the connections to that particular adresse. More [here](https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports)

Comment: The reason I have to assign an IP is to set it on my windows host file as I run multiple websites on my local machine. If I do not assign an IP, then it will default to `http://localhost:<some_port_here>`

Comment: I understand. But that does not change the way that works.

Comment: May I know what else is needed for the app to be able to do a rest call to the api endpoint? I did try your suggestion and still doesn't work.